# Catching out_of_range on a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, exception, vector, error-handling, outofrangeexception

I have a vector of vectors to establish a map of integers, and I would love to catch a vector out of range error whenever it is thrown, by doing the following:

```
vector< vector<int> > agrid(sizeX, vector<int>(sizeY));

try {
    agrid[-1][-1] = 5;     //throws an out-of-range
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    cout << "Out of Range error.";
}
```

However, my code doesn't seem to be catching the error at all. It still seems to want to run std::terminate. Does anyone know whats up with this?

Comment: Some IDE like xcode will report an error. Generally you want to use "at"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In case you want it to throw an exception, use [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)<sup>1</sup> instead of [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at):

```
try {
    agrid.at(-1).at(-1) = 5;
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    cout << "Out of Range error.";
}
```

<sup>1 - Returns a reference to the element at specified location `pos`, with bounds checking. If `pos` is not within the range of the container, an exception of type `std::out_of_range` is thrown</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The std::vector::operator [] (size_type) does not apply any range check (which is good). The function std::vector::at(size_type) does (which is good for lazy programmers). Hence ensure a proper range or check first and throw some useful exception (if you actually have to do it).

(Note: In debug compilations it might be different)